# Microsoft JDBC driver URL with Kerberos authentication and ServerSpn

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, kerberos

I have MS SQL setup with default instance in Windows authentication mode. Also I have Kerberos implemented with `ServerSpn` as MSSQlSvc.

I am trying to access the SQL Server remotely from my Java client on a Windows OS.

The Java client is executed with following JVM Paramters:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=path_to_file/client.conf
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=path_to_file/krb5.ini
```

The URL I am using looks like follows:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLSvc/FQDN_OF_SQL_Server:PORT;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

But I am getting the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host MSSQLSvc/FQDN_OF_SQL_Server, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null.
>   Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL
>   Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the
>   port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall.".   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:242)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2293)
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:506)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1523)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1040)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:554)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1019)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   microsoftJdbcDriver.getConnection(microsoftJdbcDriver.java:32)    at
>   microsoftJdbcDriver.displayDbProperties(microsoftJdbcDriver.java:51)
>     at microsoftJdbcDriver.main(microsoftJdbcDriver.java:93)

The `client.conf` file:

```
SQLJDBCDriver {    
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required    
useTicketCache=true      
doNotPrompt=true 
};
```

The `kb5.ini`:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
        clockskew = 300

[realms]
        MYDOMAIN.COM = {
                kdc = MYDOMAIN.COM
                admin_server = MYDOMAIN.COM
}


[domain_realm]
        .domain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
        domain.com> = <MYDOMAIN.COM



[appdefaults]
autologin = true
forward = true
forwardable = true
encrypt = true'
```

**Also note:**

1. The firewall is not an issue the same thing works well with native
   authentication, using `sql_auth.dll`.
2. The SQL Management Studio can also access the instance

Comment: Since you are on Windows, why don't you use SSPI implemenation with the DLL. It should be easier.

Comment: I am looking a solution which will work for non-windows as a client as well. with little modifications. Going iterative. windows to windows - native authentication works, now trying kerberos  windows to windows, then linux to windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My URL was incorrect. Surprisingly some trial and error worked:

> ```
> "jdbc:sqlserver://HOST_NAME:1433;ServerSpn=MSSQLSvc/FQDN_OF_THE_HOST:1433@REALM_NAME_IN_CAPS;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;EncryptionMethod=ssl"
> ```